# Prove that set is compact

Tags: analysis, metric-spaces

I don't know how to prove this:

Prove that set $$A:= \left\{ x=(x_n)_{n=1}^\infty \in l^2 : \sum_{n=1}^\infty{n^2x_n^2 \leq{1}} \right\}$$ is compact in $l^2$

My attempt:

Suppose there is a cover by open sets we can extract a finite cover

Thanks

Comment: It seems like it would be quite difficult to show that $A$ is compact using the finite cover definition. I would either try to show that $A$ is sequentially compact, or that $A$ is complete and totally bounded.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Note that $l^2$ is a metric space. Thus, it suffices to show that every sequence in $A$ has a convergent subsequence.

Indeed, note that for all $n$, for all $x \in A$, $x_n \in [-\frac{1}{n}, \frac{1}{n}]$.

Now suppose we have a sequence $y$ in $A$; that is, $y_n \in A$ for all $n$.

For each $n \geq 0$, pick a sequence $s_n$, which is a subsequence of $y$, as follows:

$s_0$ should be $y$ itself.

$s_{i + 1}$ should be a subsequence of $y$ such that the sequence $((s_{i + 1})_j)_{i + 1} \in [-\frac{1}{i + 1}, \frac{1}{i + 1}]$ converges. Further, define $q_{i + 1} = \lim\limits_{j \to \infty} ((s_{i + 1})_j)_{i + 1}$.

Note that for all $j$, for all $i \leq j$, we have $\lim\limits_{k \to \infty} (((s_j)_k)_i) = q_i$. Note further that this convergence is uniform in $j$ since each $s_j$ is a subsequence of $s_i$.

Define $z_i = (s_i)_i$. Then we see that $\lim\limits_{j \to \infty} (z_j)_i = q_i$ using the uniform convergence of the limit $\lim\limits_{k \to \infty} (((s_j)_k)_i) = q_i$ in $j$.

Now note that $\sum\limits_{n = 1}^\infty \frac{1}{n^2}$ converges. We can use this fact to show that $z$ converges to $y$ in $l^2$ (not just pointwise). And we see that $q_i \in [-\frac{1}{n}, \frac{1}{n}]$ for all $n$, since $q_i = \lim\limits_{j \to \infty} ((s_i)_j)_i$ and each $((s_i)_j)$ is in $A$.

Finally, note that $z$ is a subsequence of $y$.

Thus, we see that every sequence in $A$ has a convergent subsequence. Then $A$ is compact.